# Nested for loop in Scala not iterating through out the file?

Tags: scala

I have first file with data as

```
A,B,C
B,E,F
C,N,P
```

And second file with data as below

```
A,B,C,YES
B,C,D,NO
C,D,E,TRUE
D,E,F,FALSE
E,F,G,NO
```

I need every record in the first file to iterate with all records in the second file. But it's happening only for the first record.

Below is the code:

```
import scala.io.Source.fromFile

object TestComparision  {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val lines = fromFile("C:\\Users\\nreddy26\\Desktop\\Spark\\PRI.txt").getLines
      val lines2 = fromFile("C:\\Users\\nreddy26\\Desktop\\Spark\\LKP.txt").getLines
      var l = 0
      var cnt = 0
      for (line <- lines) {

        for (line2 <- lines2) {

          val cols = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
          println(s"${cols(0)}|${cols(1)}|${cols(2)}")

          val cols2 = line2.split(",").map(_.trim)
          println(s"${cols2(0)}|${cols2(1)}|${cols2(2)}|${cols2(3)}")


        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Were able to get the output like this below:
A,B,C

A,B,C,YES

A,B,C

B,C,D,NO

A,B,C

C,D,E,TRUE

A,B,C

D,E,F,FALSE

A,B,C

E,F,G,NO



B,E,F

A,B,C,YES

B,E,F

B,C,D,NO

B,E,F

C,D,E,TRUE

B,E,F

D,E,F,FALSE

B,E,F

E,F,G,NO




C,N,P

A,B,C,YES

C,N,P

B,C,D,NO

C,N,P

C,D,E,TRUE

C,N,P

D,E,F,FALSE

C,N,P

E,F,G,NO

Comment: every row in first set should iterate with second set of data but for me its happening only for first record.

Comment: **Iterators** are only consumed once, so you either need to re-open the file every time, or cache their contents in memory by turning them into a **List** or a **Vector**.

Comment: thanks will perform it

Answer (score 1):

As rightly suggested by @Luis, get the lines in `List` form by using `toList`:

```
val lines = fromFile("C:\\Users\\nreddy26\\Desktop\\Spark\\PRI.txt").getLines.toList
val lines2 = fromFile("C:\\Users\\nreddy26\\Desktop\\Spark\\LKP.txt").getLines.toList
```